# Admob with Unity3d, Ad does not appear in bottom

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I use this code as mentioned in document of play services for Unity3d.

```
BannerView bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, adSize, AdPosition.Bottom);
```

The code works, but here is the problem:
For Samsung phones I do not have any problem because, back-home buttons are not on screen. But I have another physical device for testing: LG
For Lg, I got a problem. Back, home etc buttons on screen, so when I use `AdPosition.Bottom`, It deploys it in bottom but make a space for buttons. So it is not appear in exact bottom.

Do you have suggestions?

Comment: Happens on my end too.